# Error 404 accessing to a SubResource in a JAX-RS Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have these 2 resources

```
@Path("/orders")
public class OrderResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getOrder(@PathParam("id") String orderid)
            throws JSONException {
        Order order = db.getOrder(orderid);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(order).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{orderid}/products")
    public ProductResource getProducts() {
        return new ProductResource();
    }

}

@Path("/")
public class ProductResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{productid}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getProduct(@PathParam("orderid") String orderid, @PathParam("productid") String productid) throws JSONException {
        Product product = db.getProduct(productid);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(product).build();
    }
}
```

I get a successful output when I do this:

```
http://localhost:8080/testApp/api/orders/O101
```

I can see the collection of the products linked to the order in the output so I copied the id and tried this

```
http://localhost:8080/testApp/api/orders/O101/products/P101
```

But I always get a 404 error. Why? How can I solve this?

This is my config in the web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**EDIT**

Thank you so much for your answers. Woke up this morning tired to test it with no success.

I tried your suggestions, but still get 404.

```
@Path("/orders")
public class OrderResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getOrder(@PathParam("id") String orderid)
            throws JSONException {
        Order order = db.getOrder(orderid);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(order).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{orderid}/products") //Here I added after products /{productID} which gives me an empty JSON. Never reach the method from the subresource.
    public ProductResource getProducts() {
        return new ProductResource();
    }

}

public class ProductResource {

    @Path("/{productid}")  //Here I tried to remove the slash also.
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getProduct(@PathParam("orderid") String orderid, @PathParam("productid") String productid) throws JSONException {
        Product product = db.getProduct(productid);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(product).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe OrderResource needs to have a subresource that returns a ProductResource.  Remove the `@GET` from `getProducts`

Comment: You forget add path param @PathParam("orderid") String orderid in getProducts

Comment: Thank you so much for you comments. Look at my edit. I still get the 404

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I am working on a similar issue at the moment. Did you ever find a solution? I think the solution might be to use the regex syntax to overcome an issue with a slash, but I still need to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `@GET` on the `getProducts`. A sub-resource locator is defined as a method with a `@Path` and which has *no* `@METHOD`. If you think about it, it makes perfect sense, as the there can be more than say just a `@GET` in the sub-resource class. So remove the `@GET`, and it should work. Leaving it would cause the method to *not be* a sub-resource locator, and it would behave like a normal resource method.

Aside from that, what others have suggested about the `@Path("/")` is not the cause of the problem, but it *is* a problem. What this does is cause Jersey to also register the `ProductsResource` as a root resource. So would be able to access `/api/1234`, since it is mapped to `/`. You probably don't want this. So you should remove the `@Path("/")` from the `ProductsResource`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer. Look at my edit. I still get the 404.

Comment: 1. You didn't remove the `@GET` from the `getProducts()`. 2. You need to add the `@GET` back to the method in the sub-resource class

Answer (score 0):

Sub-resources shouldn't be annotated with `@Path` on class level and they need to be registered with the JAX-RS runtinme.

Just remove the `@Path` annotation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer. Look at my edit. I still get the 404.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the problem seems to be the annotation @Path in your sub-resource. When defining a sub-resource, it should not be annotated at the class level with @Path. Also in your ProductResource, try removing the '/' from @Path("/{productid}") as it should be referenced from the context of the parent(OrderResource) and should not exists as an individual instance.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer. Look at my edit. I still get the 404.

Comment: Oh I see, let me try out a sample code, if successful will share it with you :-)